# Difference between constraint and where in partitioned view

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

On my new work I found partitioned view in SQL Server 2008 Enterprise like this:

```
...
SELECT     *
FROM [SERVER1].DATA_2012_7_1.dbo.DATA WITH (nolock)
WHERE     DateTime >= '2012-07-01' AND DateTime <= '2012-07-15 23:59:59.997'
UNION ALL
SELECT     *
FROM [SERVER2].DATA_2012_7_16.dbo.DATA WITH (nolock)
WHERE     DateTime >= '2012-07-16' AND DateTime <= '2012-07-31 23:59:59.997'
UNION ALL
...
```

Before, when I created partitioned views, always I added CONSTRAINT in tables by date columns. But in my example all tables which use in this view don't have CONSTRAINT.
What are you think about difference? Will be both views work right and equally quickly?

Answer (score 1):

From [Using Partitioned Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> CHECK constraints are not needed for the partitioned view to return the correct results. However, if the CHECK constraints have not been defined, the query optimizer must search all the tables instead of only those that cover the search condition on the partitioning column. Without the CHECK constraints, the view operates like any other view with UNION ALL. The query optimizer cannot make any assumptions about the values stored in different tables and it cannot skip searching the tables that participate in the view definition.

So, it may not perform equally well (for queries where the `CHECK` constraints could have eliminated some partitions).

---

The query optimizer *may* be smart enough to *effectively* perform partition elimination based on the intersection between the `WHERE` clauses internal to the view and whatever conditions are applied in the query in which the view is accessed - but in choosing between a *documented* way to achieve elimination (`CHECK` constraints) and an undocumented one (optimizer combining `WHERE` clauses and other conditions), I know which one I'd choose.